# Parametrizing a Date on urls.py in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the following URL definition:

```
url(r'^date-add/(?P<entity_id>\d+)$', views.date_add, name='date_add'),
```

That allows me to call date_add function with the following URL:

```
/app_name/date-add/<id>
```

I would like to fix this to allow a date. For example:

```
/app_name/date-add/1/2013-04-23
```

How should I edit my urls.py definition in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your URL regex like this:

```
url(r'^date-add/(?P<entity_id>\d+)/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.date_add, name='date_add'),
```

and the view, obviously would be

```
def date_add(request, entity_id, date):
    #convert to datetime object from string here.
```

Comment: Question: Does ''?P'' stand for the parameter name?

Comment: `?P` stands for a pattern match in a named group. In python, this is the syntax for "named regular-expression groups" `(?P<name>pattern)`. Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Answer (score 2):

Typically you break it down into named parameters corresponding to the year, month and date:

```
url(r'^date-add/(?P<entity_id>\d+)/(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$', views.date_add, name='date_add_with_param'),
```

Then you can use `datetime.date` to construct the datetime in your view, which should receive `year`, `month` and `day` as parameters.

This is the usual pattern in particular for archive views, where the URLs might get more specific as you drill down - /archive/2013/ and /archive/2013/11/ might both be valid, although of course you probably wouldn't have a single regexp matching either. It might be unnecessarily complex compared to the single named pattern regexp karthikr's answer shows, which you could then parse with `datetime.strptime`.

In either case you can also use somewhat more restrictive regexps if you like, like ones that don't allow a first digit other than 0, 1, 2 or 3 for the month.

Comment: Thanks, the earlier reply was faster though :/